How would you approach this basement drywall repair?
This section of the wall (it may be plaster) was removed to install a French drain which you can barely make out in the picture.
I'm thinking of using tapcons and glue to adhere drywall to this section since there's not a lot of room to work with for furring strips. I'm concerned about humidity given the French drain, although the back of this wall is not exterior; it leads to a closet.
Other than drywall, what other alternatives should I explore?



Looks like it was previously simply glued to the block?

I'm not clear on what you're calling a "French drain". The term simply means a gravity-operated drain to another part of the property. Where is the moisture likely to be here?

What kind of finish is currently on the wall? I agree, it looks like some drywall had been glued up before.

There is a French drain installed under the steps. You can kind of see it by the first step of the staircase. Agree with the glue, will attempt to do that.

I would make very thin furring strips, just for support, or use a metal mesh. Then use the traditional plastering method of sequential layers of hot mud, adding 1/8" to 1/4" at a time until it's at the same level as the rest of the drywall. Then a final layer of lightweight joint compound.
